# How to disable/enable the ctrl+alt+delete combinations key using pyhook?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, pyhook

I have referred [this link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553270-using-pyhook-to-block-windows-keys/) and disabled some of the combination keys but I am unable to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>. Please let me know if it is possible to disable using pyhook or any other alternative solution using python code.